# Wiki text Google Documents altered

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki, moderation

I was a bit surprised to see the wiki text of the [google-documents](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-documents) tag being altered:
[image]

See link for full history: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/posts/37832/revisions

Especially because @Hydry and myself prepared it.

Perhaps the moderator, that approved the wiki mod @Al made, can enlighten me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Altered sounds like there is a certain ownership to it. Anyone with editing privileges can take part in shaping up a tag wiki. So the correct question to ask the community and your fellow users is whether tag usage should be included in the tag wiki.

Comment: That's already known: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/10398923#10398923,
"What questions should have this tag"

Comment: So, am I to understand that each revision will be accepted by the moderators?

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra no, I trusted Al's edit and it seemed valid based on his summary of "Reduced amount of verbiage". If an edit goes way out of its way or totally different direction then I probably wouldn't approve it. Again, this comes down to tag wiki content guidelines for WebApps which should probably be posted as a meta post so in the future people can be directed to it.

Comment: I find it quite rude to make these modifications, without prior notice (as an active user (me) to another active user (Al)). You should have taken that into account.

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra You are making this a tad personal when it really shouldn't be, I'm sorry that I've made you feel this way. I have added the usage section back for you http://webapps.stackexchange.com/revisions/37832/5 and I've added a meta post asking the community to discuss how best to write tag wikis for WebApps http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/2542/how-to-write-a-tag-wiki

Comment: Good golly, that was months ago. I can't remember back that far. In any event, I think the guidance for what tags to use _with_ [tag:google-documents] is unnecessary and will probably do more harm than good. We already know people _don't read_ on the Internet. Further, the tags on a question should be able to stand alone. If you _have_ to use them in combination with others, then something is wrong. I decided to **be bold** and make what I thought were good changes. @Jacob, you disagree. Okay, great. Now we should open a dialog here and collaborate. No one should be offended.